# Как перевернуть ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю калькулятор, и хочу в листбокс отправлять историю. Но нужно чтоб она была не сверху вниз, а снизу вверх, то есть мне нужно развернуть данные в листбоксе. Как это сделать, и возможно ли вообще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Измените макет ItemsPanel (**[ОТВЕТ ВЗЯТ ТУТ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153296/present-listbox-items-bottom-to-top/9153353#9153353)**:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще можно использовать метод [Insert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.insert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1_Insert_System_Int32__0_).

```
items.Insert(0, newItem);
```