# Как расположить объекты в ListBox горизонтально?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SimilarArtist}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

[image: Last_FM]

На картинке я указал как у меня должны расположиться объекты но что бы я не делал мне выводится обычный вертикальный список имён.

Можете подсказать как их расположить горизонтально? Или что использовать вместо StackPanel?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перевернуть ListBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/976066/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-listbox)

Comment: Верно, нужно переопределить `ListBox.ItemsPanel`